# startx not working

Tags: boot, bash, xorg, asus, chroot

I am attempting to install Ubuntu on an ASUS T100. However, when I boot it manually from GRUB, it crashes into an intramfs shell. I am able to mount the filesystem from the intramfs ASH shell and chroot into the root partition, and thus a BASH shell but from there whenever I attempt to start the X server it loads but crashes with "no devices detected" and then "no screens found". Whenever I attempt to run X -configure I come up with similar errors. I am not sure if X server is having issues or if chroot normally causes X problems or something else. I am posting my Xorg log file below.

```
[   198.375] 
X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
[   198.383] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   198.386] Build Operating System: Linux 3.19.0-30-generic x86_64   
Ubuntu
[   198.388] Current Operating System: Linux (none) 4.2.0-16-generic  
#19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64
[   198.391] Build Date: 30 September 2015  09:08:47AM
[   198.394] xorg-server 2:1.17.2-1ubuntu9 (For technical support please 
see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)  
[   198.396] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[   198.401]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   198.401] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default 
setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   198.412] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Jan  3 
08:21:57 2016
[   198.421] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share 
/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   198.425] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   198.425] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   198.425] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   198.425] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"  
[   198.426] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen 
Section".
Using a default monitor configuration.
[   198.426] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   198.426] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   198.426] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   198.426] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not 
exist.
[   198.426]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   198.426] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not 
exist.
[   198.426]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   198.426] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not 
exist.
[   198.426]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   198.426] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not 
exist.
[   198.426]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   198.426] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not 
exist.
[   198.426]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   198.426] (==) FontPath set to:
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
built-ins
[   198.426] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg
/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   198.426] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input 
devices.
If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable 
AutoAddDevices.
[   198.427] (II) Loader magic: 0x55a268a2bd40
[   198.427] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   198.427]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   198.427]    X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
[   198.427]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[   198.427]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[   198.427] (II) no primary bus or device found
[   198.427] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   198.429] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   198.444] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   198.444]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   198.444]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[   198.444] (==) AIGLX enabled
[   198.444] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[   198.444] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   198.444] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[   198.444] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   198.444] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   198.445] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers
/modesetting_drv.so
[   198.446] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   198.446]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.17.2
[   198.446]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   198.446]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[   198.446] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   198.446] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   198.447] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   198.447]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.4.4
[   198.447]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   198.447]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[   198.447] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   198.447] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   198.448] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   198.448]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.3.4
[   198.448]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   198.448]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[   198.448] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   198.448] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   198.448] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   198.448] (--) using VT number 2

[   198.469] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   198.470] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   198.470] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   198.470] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   198.470] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   198.471] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   198.472] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   198.472]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 0.0.2
[   198.472]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[   198.472] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[   198.472] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[   198.472] (EE) No devices detected.
[   198.472] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[   198.472] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   198.472] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[   198.472] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   198.472] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   198.473] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers
/modesetting_drv.so
[   198.473] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   198.473]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.17.2
[   198.473]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   198.473]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[   198.473] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   198.473] (II) Unloading modesetting
[   198.473] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 
21922)
[   198.473] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   198.473] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   198.473] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   198.473]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.4.4
[   198.473]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   198.473]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[   198.473] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   198.473] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   198.473] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 21922)
[   198.474] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   198.474] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   198.474] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   198.474]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.3.4
[   198.474]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   198.474]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[   198.474] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   198.474] (II) Unloading vesa
[   198.474] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 21922)
[   198.474] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   198.474] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   198.474] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   198.474] (++) using VT number 2

[   198.474] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setpgid failed: Operation not 
permitted
[   198.474] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setsid failed: Operation not permitted
[   198.474] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   198.474] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   198.474] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   198.474] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   198.474] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   198.475] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   198.475] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   198.475]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 0.0.2
[   198.475]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[   198.475] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[   198.475] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[   198.475] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[   198.475] (EE) No devices detected.
[   198.475] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   198.475] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   198.475] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support  
at http://wiki.x.org
for help. 
[   198.475] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log
/Xorg.0.log" 
for additional information.
[   198.475] (EE) 
[   198.518] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: Before running startx in a chroot environment you must mount --bind /dev, /proc and /sys.

Comment: @EduardoCola I did that and at least now I have a standard background screen up. Is there something else I missed? No logon screen or interface is loaded.